# Go to next step if field is valid EnjoyHint()

Tags: javascript, jquery, enjoyhint

I want go to the next step in tour if field not empty.
Full code:

```
var EnjoyHintWizard = /**@class*/ (function () {
    function EnjoyHintWizard() {
        var _this = this;
        this.enjoyhint_instance = new EnjoyHint({});

        this.enjoyhint_script_steps = [                
            {
                'key .field-survey-name' : __('input_survey_name'),
                keyCode : 13,
                showSkip: false
            },
            {
                'next .form-builder-start-page' : __('select_element'),
                nextButton: {
                    text: __('next')
                },
                showSkip: false
            },
            {
                'click .tab-questions' : __('select_element'),
                showSkip: false
            },               
            {
                'click .fa-map-marker' : __('go_to_point'),
                showSkip: false
            },
            {
                'click .btn-add_point' : __('click_on_btn_add_point'),
                showSkip: false
            },
            {
                'key .input-point-name' : __('fill_this_fields'),
                keyCode: 13,
                showSkip: false
            },
            {
                'custom .fields-add-point' : __('fill_this_fields'),
                event: function () {

                },
                onBeforeStart: function () {
                    console.log('this');
                   //_this.enjoyhint_instance.trigger('click_enter');
                    // var inputField = $('.input-point-name').find('input[type="text"]');
                    // console.log(inputField);
                    // $(document).ready(function() {
                    //     inputField.keyup(function (event) {
                    //         if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                    //             console.log('entered');
                    //             if (inputField.val() || inputField.val() !== '') {
                    //                 _this.enjoyhint_instance.trigger('click_enter');
                    //             }
                    //         }
                    //     });
                    // });
                },
                showSkip: false
            },
            {
                'custom .btn-save-point' : __('click_save_point'),
                event: 'custom_event_name',
                onBeforeStart: function () {
                        _this.enjoyhint_instance.trigger('custom_event_name');
                        console.log(_this.enjoyhint_instance.getCurrentStep());
                },
                showSkip: false
            },               
            {
                'click .btn-download-sticker' : __('click_btn_download'),
                skipButton: {
                    text: __('skip')
                }
            }
        ];
    }

    EnjoyHintWizard.prototype.startTour = function () {
        this.enjoyhint_instance.set(this.enjoyhint_script_steps);
        this.enjoyhint_instance.run();
    };

    EnjoyHintWizard.prototype.resumeTour = function () {
        this.enjoyhint_instance.reRunScript(13);
    };       
    return EnjoyHintWizard;
}());
```

When i press button Enter exec next step although previous field if empty.
It is my all code. I try add trigger for custom event but it not helped.
I look in official documentation but hes very short https://github.com/xbsoftware/enjoyhint

Comment: Please give complete code

Comment: @SourabhSomani Added full code. Look pleas.

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve] in a JsFiddle or snippet... It would be much easier to help since we could test the code, also, in which step it should go next if it is valid? All of them or which ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using next way:

```
 {
    'custom .input-name' : __('fill_name'),
     event: 'enter_name',
     showSkip: false,
     onBeforeStart: function () {
        this.isValid('input-name', 'enter_name');
     }
 }
```

I'd make custom event for go to the next step and use it method `onBefforeStart` inside I valid field and if it valid call event to go to the next step of tour.